BCa Bootstrap Confidence Intervals for Clustered Data
I want to compute a confidence interval for the F1-score of a machine learning model for the classification of blood cells on test data. The data is clustered, as I have multiple cells for every patient. My plan is to compute bias-corrected and accelerated (BCa) bootstrap confidence intervals. For this, I need to

Bootstrap the test data
Compute the acceleration factor using the jackknife

My question is: at which level should I resample the data during bootstrapping and jackknifing?
Here are the options I am considering:

Patient level: Bootstrap patients; leave-one-patient-out for the jackknife
Cell level: Usual bootstrapping / jackknifing on observation level
Both patient level and cell level: Bootstrap patients, and for each bootstrapped patient, bootstrap cells from this patient; for the jackknife, this approach does not seem practical as it would reduce to the usual jackknife (leave one observation out).

My intuition suggests resampling at the patient level for both bootstrap and jackknife to avoid underestimating the variance of the test data. However, I am looking for a solid reference or argument to support this choice, particularly for the jackknife.
Could anyone provide guidance or references from the literature on why resampling at the patient level might be preferable, especially for the jackknife?
